# Jira: Assign permission based on Groups

Tags: jira, jira-agile

I have 14 people in 5 teams.  Some are overlapping.  i.e  A couple of `Web` team members are part of the `Server` team.

I am not sure if this is the right way, but I would like to manage each `team` with their own `Jira` `project`.

Thus, I have 5 projects:

`Mobile`

`Design`

`Web`

`Server`

`Hardware`

I would like to assign access to `projects` based on `Group`. i.e. `Mobile` `project` should only be accessed by a `Group` name `Mobile Developers`.  `Design` `project` should only be accessed by the `Design Team Group`. `Design` should NOT have access to the `Mobile` `project`.

How do I accomplish this on `Jira Cloud`?

Currently I have two `Permission Scheme`:
[image]

`Default software scheme` shows all 5 of my projects.  I can only edit the `Name` and `Description`.  When I click on `Permissions` it takes me to a screen that says:

[image]

How can I assign `permission` to each individual `project` based on `Group`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone your default permission scheme and create a custom permission scheme for each project.

For example:

> Mobile Project Permission Scheme

Next, assign the new permission schemes to the projects. So the Mobile project uses the Mobile Project Permission Scheme, the Web project uses the Web Project Permission Scheme, etc.

At this stage, there is no new behaviour as all the projects are using the same permission scheme, just they now have their own copies of the scheme. That means any changes you make to a custom permission scheme will only impact on one project.

Now, edit the permission schemes and give permissions based on the groups.

e.g.

> Manage Sprints   -   Mobile_User_Group